# How can I shorten the cable on an outlet bar?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have several long outlet bars I'd like to install under a cabinet.  I'm not interested in hard-wiring them, so I will plug them into some existing outlets.

The problem is that I only need about 2 feet of cable to reach the outlets, rather than the 6ft that comes attached to the outlet bar.

How can I shorten the cable?

Comment: Sometimes I have been known to use an axe.

Comment: Cut off the plug and use a replacement, with screw terminals.

Comment: you don't have a place to place the coil of cable? That's the simpler solution

Comment: @ratchetfreak's suggestion also is ideal for when you need to move the power strip later in life.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what cord/plug you have right now.

If you currently have a removable plug then you open it up (usually one or two screws), unscrew the wires, cut the cord where you want it, strip the outer sheath, strip the individual wires and reattach.

If you currently have a molded cord/plug then you'll have to chop off the cord at the length you want, strip the outer sheath, strip the individual wires and attach a new connector such as [this one from Leviton](https://amzn.to/3SU9nRq):

[image: Leviton yellow 15a plug]

I recommend sticking with a major manufacturer and look for UL or ETL listing. (Amazon doesn't show it, but Leviton's own site says it is UL/CSA listed.) Also make sure it is designed for heavy duty cords. Due to the way the US system works, you can find NEMA 15 stuff that is really only designed for much less than 15A current. You want something that actually says it can handle 15A and that fits at least 14 AWG wire (this will handled up to 12 AWG).

Comment: Go to your favorite box store, most in our area sell them with 18" and/or 24" cords.

Comment: Is shortening a power cord considered modifying an electrical device?  Did I see/read something about not being quite code?  Know just replacing a plug is okay, so just wondering.

Comment: @crip659 interesting point. Many outlet strips - the kind designed for workbenches, not the typical consumer surge protectors -  are designed to have varying length cords.